# No module found 'google.cloud.vision.feature'

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

Until recently I was able to run a Python script in which I used:

```
from google.cloud.vision.feature import *
```

During the last day, I tried it again but I get the error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.vision.feature'; 'google.cloud.vision' is not a package

Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/python-client-migration#deprecated_modules), `google.cloud.vision.feature` is one of the deprecated modules in v0.25.1 onwards. If you do not wish to migrate to the newest version you can force to use the old one with `google-cloud-vision==0.25` in `requirements.txt` or using pip:

```
pip install google-cloud-vision==0.25
```

Otherwise, you'll need to take into account the [required code changes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/python-client-migration#required_code_changes) and adapt it depending on what you want to do.